# jQuery list box onChange refresh second list box options

Tags: jquery, forms, select, drop-down-menu, listbox

I have a search form where the user can select an Event, Region, Local Authority, Venue, etc. The Region, Local Authority and Venue search fields are list boxes.

Both the Local Authority and Venue are assigned to a Region so what I'm wanting to do is update these two drop-downs when a Region is selected from the list so that only relevant values are displayed to the user.

Is there a way of doing this with jQuery that doesn't require me to submit the form as this will perform the query although the user may not have selected all search fields they want to?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#IDofRegionList').change(function(){
      $("select").remove();
      $("IDofVenue").append ("<option value=anything> anything </option>");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work in essence but the added difficulty is that I'm then looping round the Venue drop-down using a query that uses the Region ID to get the Venues to populate the list with...